# .vimrc in local folder

Tags: vimrc

Can I have a `.vimrc` file in local folder, so that each time I open files in that folder, vim will automatically load that `.vimrc` file? so that I can have different settings in different folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See [`:help 'exrc'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27exrc%27). But don't skip the part that says: `BETTER NOT SET THIS OPTION!`

We also have a [few](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/77/applying-settings-to-a-directory-tree-only) [earlier](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/how-to-make-vimrc-settings-applicable-for-a-directory-tree-only/2134#2134) [questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/is-there-a-way-to-make-some-modeline-that-applies-to-all-files-in-a-directory-r/20908#20908) for which the answers detail alternative approaches.